# String index out of range error

Tags: python, string, indexing

Hey i keep getting a string index out of range error... i have tried EVERYTHING could you please help out, Thanks a hell of a lot appreciated.

```
x = 0
y = ""
z = 0
user_input = raw_input("Message? ")

while z < len(user_input):
    y = y + " " + user_input[x]
    x = x +3
    z += 1
    if x > len(user_input):
         print y
         break
```

Comment: You should mark this question as answered, please.

Answer (score 3):

You only break when `if x > len(user_input):`. But what if `x % 3 == 0`?

That means the length of your input string is dividable by three. You increment `x` by three each time and when the length of your input string is a multiple of three you'll get an error.

To fix it, you should use `if x >= len(user_input):` instead.

Comment: Thus, the OP should use `>=` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 1):

if user_input is a multiple of 3, then x will eventually equal the length of user_input (and the index will be one greater than actually exists).

```
user_input = "abc"
```

If someone answers your user_input with that, then you'll have a length of 3, but the index will only go up to 2 (user_input[0] == "a", user_input[1] == "b", user_input[2] == "c", user_input[3] throws an IndexError).

Instead, change your if statement to look like this:

```
while x >= len(user_input):
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `if` condition should read `x >= len(user_input)`? (`user_input[x]` with `x` being `len(user_input)` is probably giving you trouble)